# Unable to run or build images in podman

Tags: containers, podman

I recently tried to install podman on my mac.
`podman machine init` and `podman machine start` seem to work.

```
podman machine list
NAME                     VM TYPE     CREATED      LAST UP            CPUS        MEMORY      DISK SIZE
podman-machine-default*  qemu        2 hours ago  Currently running  1           2.147GB     10.74GB

podman system connection list
Name                         Identity                                    URI
podman-machine-default*      /Users/k/.ssh/podman-machine-default  ssh://core@localhost:65137/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
podman-machine-default-root  /Users/k/.ssh/podman-machine-default  ssh://root@localhost:65137/run/podman/podman.sock
```

So these seem to be OK too...
However, when I try commands like:
`podman run -dt -p 8080:80 nginx` I get the error:

```
podman --log-level=debug run -dt -p 8080:80 nginx
INFO[0000] podman filtering at log level debug
DEBU[0000] Called run.PersistentPreRunE(podman --log-level=debug run -dt -p 8080:80 nginx)
DEBU[0000] SSH Ident Key "/Users/k/.ssh/podman-machine-default" SHA256:<redacted> ssh-ed25519
DEBU[0000] Found SSH_AUTH_SOCK "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ESzXNsREXi/Listeners", ssh-agent signer(s) enabled
DEBU[0000] DoRequest Method: GET URI: http://d/v3.4.4/libpod/_ping
DEBU[0000] Adding port mapping from 8080 to 80 length 1 protocol ""
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf"
DEBU[0000] No credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/ found
DEBU[0000] Found credentials for docker.io in credential helper containers-auth.json in file /Users/k/.config/containers/auth.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/k/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/k/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 62, in main
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import encoding
  File "/Users/k/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/Users/k/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/Users/k/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('enum')
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
DEBU[0000] Error looking up credentials for staging-k8s.gcr.io in credential helper containers-auth.json: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``
Error: 1 error occurred:
    * error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``
```

I'm at a loss as to why this exception is coming and why is it picking up google SDK. I don't think I have registered on GCR in podman....

Additionally, I logged into docker.io with podman (successful) but it still throws this error.

This is the same error if I try to build a dockerfile as well.
How do I debug this?

```
podman --version
podman version 3.4.4
```

MacOS Monterey 12.1 (Intel MacBook)

Comment: Same here, but it worked for some time after installation.